# Performance optimizations in tokio and pcap

Tags: rust, pcap, rust-tokio

### Background

I've got a program that needs to handle a lot of packets.   Ultimately, I'm looking to handle around 350k pkts/s.  To tackle this, I've iterated through several versions of code and ended up with the code below.

For reference, the code is running on an ubuntu VM with 4 dedicated cores and a NIC way bigger than is needed for this application.

### Observations

Running the below code only loads one core, for the most part.  It's mostly kernel calls, which I'm guessing is for IO.

Pcap (if accurate) is only reporting dropped packets for the program buffer -- not the interface itself.

The dropped packets are being observed with only 87k pkts/s.  I've got to significantly improve this if I want to get 4-5X data loads through it.

See the question below the code...

```
[dependencies]
pcap = { version = "1.1.0", features = ["all-features", "capture-stream"] }
tokio = { version = "1.32.0", features = ["full"] }
futures = { version = "0.3.28"}
```

```
use pcap::{Active, Capture, Inactive, Error, Packet, PacketCodec, PacketStream};
use tokio::sync::mpsc;
use futures::StreamExt;

// Simple codec that returns owned copies, since the result may not
// reference the input packet.
pub struct BoxCodec;

impl PacketCodec for BoxCodec {
    type Item = Box<[u8]>;

    fn decode(&mut self, packet: Packet) -> Self::Item {
        packet.data.into()
    }
}

fn new_stream(capture_inactive: Capture<Inactive>) -> Result<PacketStream<Active, BoxCodec>, Error> {
    let cap = capture_inactive
        .promisc(true)
        .immediate_mode(true)
        .open()?
        .setnonblock()?;
    cap.stream(BoxCodec)
}

// generate a dummy layer 2 packet that we can easily find in wireshark
async fn generate_packet() -> Vec<u8> {
    // Define source and destination MAC addresses
    let src_mac = [0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55];
    let dest_mac = [0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF];

    // Create the Ethernet frame
    let mut pkt: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

    // Destination MAC address
    pkt.extend_from_slice(&dest_mac);

    // Source MAC address
    pkt.extend_from_slice(&src_mac);

    // EtherType (0x0800 for IPv4)
    pkt.extend_from_slice(&[0x08, 0x00]);

    // Custom payload
    let payload: [u8; 10] = [0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A];
    pkt.extend_from_slice(&payload);
    
    pkt
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let capture_inactive = Capture::from_device("ens192").unwrap();

    let (tx, mut rx): (mpsc::Sender<Vec<u8>>, mpsc::Receiver<Vec<u8>>) = mpsc::channel(1024);
    let (tx_msg, mut rx_msg): (mpsc::Sender<Vec<u8>>, mpsc::Receiver<Vec<u8>>) = mpsc::channel(1024);

    // spawn the process for reading packets from the interface...
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut stream = new_stream(capture_inactive).expect("Failed to create stream");
        let mut count = 0;
        loop {
            tokio::select! {
                packet = stream.next() => { // packet is Option<Result<Box>>
                    count += 1;
                    if count % 1_000_000 == 0 {
                        let cap = stream.capture_mut();
                        let stats = cap.stats().unwrap();
                        println!(
                            "Received: {}, dropped: {}, if_dropped: {}",
                            stats.received, stats.dropped, stats.if_dropped
                        );
                    }

                    if let Some(Ok(data)) = packet {
                        let _send_result = tx.send(data.to_vec()).await;
                    }
                },
                data = rx_msg.recv() => {
                    let _ = stream.capture_mut().sendpacket(data.unwrap());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    let worker_handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut count = 0;
        loop {
            match rx.recv().await {
                Some(_packet) => {
                    count += 1;
                    if count % 100_000 == 0 {
                        println!("Processed {} packets", count);
                    }
                    if count % 100_000 == 0 {
                        let data = generate_packet().await;
                        let _msg = tx_msg.send(data).await;
                    }
                }
                None => {
                    println!("Worker task ended");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    worker_handle.await.unwrap();

}
```

Here is a screenshot showing the program output, and the htop stats.

[image: htop and program output]

### Question

What can I look at to improve performance?   Although I can't find it at the moment, I thought I read that tokio defaults to using all of the available cores.  For grins, I did run a version with the multi-thread options on tokio.  Playing with this and changing the number of available workers did not seem to impact performance in any positive way.

`#[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread", worker_threads = 8)]`

I'm trying to offload the main thread to allow it to do nothing but ingest packets, but that doesn't appear to be what's happening here.

Ideas?

Comment: the `to_vec` could be the source of slowness. Each call to that is allocating memory for the new vector, and allocations are very slow. Perhaps rework the code to instead just past around references to the data?

Comment: If you have working code, and you don't want to reach some level of performance, just to optimize it, the question may be a better fit at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I guess in a way, I am trying to optimize it, but at the same time I'm trying to understand best practices.   My background is mostly c# and python, so I'm trying not to learn (or bring over) bad habits as I move most of my code to Rust.  I wasn't aware of the codereview site, so thanks for that tip.  Btw -- using the optimized compiler options doesn't change the code performance.  I feel like I'm not not efficiently offloading to threads as much as I think I am.

Comment: "350k pkts/s" I'm a pretty good coder and I did tokio + pcap and trust me when I say that 350 000 paquet second is impossible. For this kind of speed you need direct hardware process I think. For the reference while my app do some heavy calculation and many other thing I was at max 8k/s thus on my case pcap was not the limited factor.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  The NIC is a 25Gb nic, and the CPU is not loading more than 60% with 86.5k.  So far, I've changed added:

.buffer_size(5_000_000)
.snaplen(250_000)

to the code that initializes the stream and that helps.  I've been running this version for just at 63 mins and it's only dropped 70 packets out of 334M packets.  These are layer 2 packets that are very small.  Total bandwidth is about 82Mb/s.

Comment: that will be very hard to go higher unless very oriented hardware and connection.

Comment: I had someone on codereview suggest that I remove the .immediate from the capture section.  It was disabling my buffers.  I've modified the code and it's handling right at 333k pkts/s with no drops.  It's now been running for 50 minutes and processed 1B packets. Maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You have to let go of Tokio and instead work with the LMAX disruptor.

https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/disruptor.html

Luckily there is a Rust port.

https://github.com/sklose/disrustor

From memory, if you follow the performance instructions and pin each executor to a dedicated core, you can process millions of events per second.

https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Performance-Results

Hope that helps.